# Spotify Web Apps doesn't update

Tags: html, caching, web-applications, spotify

I try to write some code on the `index.html` and when I run the app on Spotify it doesn't update. I have to quit and restart Spotify to see my updates... Is it normal ?

Is it possible to not restart Spotify entirely to get my updates ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've tried this but it doesn't say in your question (and I got to few points to just comment and ask). But you asked how to update your app and these are three ways to do it:

- Develop -> Reload application
- Right-click (anywhere in the application) -> Reload application
- Press command+alt+R (on mac, probably something with ctrl+r on windows)